# Update field in an entity with updatable=false returns the entity with the field with the new value

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa and I have an entity with the following code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
private UUID id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(updatable = false)
private long creationTimestamp;
...
```

I use a org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository to do the pertinent CRUD operations.

When I firstly save the entity (e.g. creationTimestamp=1), the method *save(entity)* returns the saved entity (like the javadoc says) with the new *id* for further operations (like the javadoc says) and with the field *creationTimestamp=1*.

But later on, if I try to update this entity with a new *creationTimestamp* (e.g. creationTimestamp=2), again with the method *save(entity)*, this method returns the entity with the field *creationTimestamp=2* (which is not correct).

If I search with the method *findById(given_id)*, the returned entity has the field *creationTimestamp=1*, which is correct because the column was defined as *updatable=false*.

The question is, why when I update, the method *save(entity)* returns the new value in *creationTimestamp* instead of the one that is in the database? Because I expect "the saved entity" (like the javadoc says).

Comment: How creationTimestamp is setted?

Comment: Can you give the class code that update and save the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option does not make the attribute write protected. It means that the UPDATE statement sent to the database shall exclude this field.

Comment: Here is a [link to some documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable()).

Comment: This doesnt answer the question of why the value that is returned does not match the value that is in the database. As the documentation says, it should return "the saved entity". 
The entire point of returning the value from the `.save()` is to get the correct database representation.

Answer (score 0):

How @Stefan said `@Column(updatable = false)` affects only database layer

[Here in Stackoverflow, there are a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993274/javax-persistence-column-updatable-false)

If I understood that you are trying to do, I recommend that Spring manage this column with

```java
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
        private UUID id;

        @Basic(optional = false)
        @CreationTimestamp
        private java.sql.Timestamp creationTimestamp;
```

Using this implementation it isn't necessary you to code to set value in this attribute. You only create getter method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case does not apply because I am using a controller which parses from json to myEntity. And even with this, if I get pass creationTimestamp, I get the wrong value as returned.

Comment: Are you aware that an EntityManager caches records?